# How do I use a shell script to keep only the last populated value for each month in a CSV?

Tags: command-line, date, csv

I have a csv file which gets updated by a cron daily and looks something like this:

Date,Value
01/11/2019,123
02/11/2019,456
03/11/2019,789
...
31/01/2020,123
01/02/2020,456
02/02/2020,789
03/02/2020,123
04/02/2020,456
05/02/2020,789

I would like the file to be updated by a shell script so that it always has the last entry for each month e.g.

Date,Value
30/11/19,123
31/12/19,456
31/01/20,789
05/02/20,789

**Note that the last populated line for each month may not be on the last day of that month**

Not sure how to approach this so would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates are already ordered, you should be able to print the previous record every time the month changes (and once more at the very end).

Ex. given

```
$ cat file.csv
Date,Value
01/11/2019,123
02/11/2019,456
03/11/2019,789
31/01/2020,123
01/02/2020,456
02/02/2020,789
03/02/2020,123
04/02/2020,456
05/02/2020,789
```

then

```
$ awk -F, '{split($1,a,"/")} a[2] != lastm {print last; lastm = a[2]} {last = $0} END {print last}' file.csv
Date,Value
03/11/2019,789
31/01/2020,123
05/02/2020,789
```

You get the header line for free since the first month value is always different from the empty string.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick answer...you're a lifesaver!